# Display message on homepage when new user account is activated

Tags: buddypress, user-registration, activation

When a new user registers on Wordpress an activation link is sent out to their email address.  When the user clicks on this link they are directed to my homepage and their account is activated.  At the moment there is nothing to indicate to the user that they are activated and I would therefore like to have a message appear on the homepage saying, “Your account is now activated. You can now login” when a user clicks on the activation link.

Does anyone know how this would be implemented?  I am using the Buddypress plugin. I don't think makes a difference to default wordpress behaviour but thought it may be worth mentioning.

I am using Wordpress v4.1.2

Thanks in advance for your help.